# Transparent tkinter frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, frame, python-2.x, transparent

Dear Stackoverflow community;

I am working on a Touchscreen application.
For this work I need to Change the window if a user clicks on it.
My code:

```
def init(win):
def getclick(event):
     parent.destroy()
     openSubWindow(dialog);
frame = Frame(win, width=650, height=550)
frame.bind("", getclick)
frame.pack()
win.title("Ausgangsposition")
win.minsize(650, 550)
```

I used the following idea:
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm
The idea:
Create a Frame which overlays the whole window, click on frame means changing window.
Is there any way, to get the frame transparent or is my idea completly wrong? At the Moment the frame hides all my Labels in this Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Could you evaluate the folllowing aproaches?

1. remove the frame

   ```
   frame.pack_forget() # remove
   frame.pack() # place it there again
   ```
2. create a toplevel widget that is above the frame all the time. It can have transparencies from 0 to 100
3. Try to put the frame behind the other elements and raise the frame above the other elements.

Comment: I want to do this with the Frame, if there isn't a better Option. Could you explain me more to aproach #3?

Comment: No I can not. Sorry. Have you tried #1? I do not know how to do #3. But there is a order in painting the widgets on the screen. The idea was to exploit that.